# Displaying advertisement previews in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a website with ads on it, and people can purchase ad space. The person I'm creating the website for wants to be able to preview live pages with "example" ads (it's basically a placeholder ad with the pixel size on it, they are just images that have already been generated).

So they want to be able to see, for example, the LIVE blog page but with the current ads replaced by the placeholder ads to preview it to the people purchasing ad space.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. If it was just for the homepage I'd probably to an if/else to display the right ad div, but this is occurring on 5-6 pages. I've tried using page variants but I can't get them to work at all.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a very simple approach to implement this kind of functionality.
You might use `$_GET` requests in your URLs to show a live example.

I might be wrong, but as far as I remember, any `$_GET` request will result in `X-Drupal-Cache:MISS`, therefore you might use [drupal_get_query_parameters](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7) to check the URL for a query and alter the output.

And then you might use `http://example.com/?client=demo1` to show your "conditional" ads.

Comment: Would I implement this functionality into the page.tpl.php file?

Comment: @swinkel Yes, you _can_ do that, but I wouldn't recommend polluting any `*.tpl.php` file with PHP logic. There is a huge variety of ways, how you might implement that, the easiest I could think of is something with [Custom Blocks](https://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7) or ideally [Custom Panes](https://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/creating-custom-panels-panes-and-use-substitution-too), but if you're not that expirienced with Drupal, then the solution with `*.tpl.php` will work.